Changes to code don't apply if i use IDE when i compile Java with Maven for Tomcat
When i use "maven clean install compile" for my java project in Eclipse, NetBeans or VSCode, and then move files to my Tomcat server folder my code doesn't change on my server, and when i open java files in src folder -- even though in Eclipse code is new and saved i can see how *.java files are often (that is strange) in their older versions. If i update manually w/o IDE it works as expected, but when i use maven and Tomcat server in any of these 3 IDEs -- it doesn't work.
Important thing is that for first couple of days it worked just fine and i used it, but after some days in Eclipse this problem has occurred, i switched to NetBeans, but after 1 day this occurred there too, and i've tried VSCode and it occured after 1 or 3 compilations.
I didn't change anything and it stopped working. I refreshed the project, manually deleted target folder, checked if i had Compile on save turned on (i had), restarted the server, published to server, but nothing helps yet

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
